# What kind of promise does the promisified MongoDB Node driver .forEach() return?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, promise, bluebird

I have recently started using arrow functions, promises (bluebird) and MongoDB in my Node.js project. As you can see below, I promisified all the mongodb native driver. So far, works like a charm.

Now, I would like to use the .forEach() method, and I wonder how I should use it. Here is the idea :

```js
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var mongodb = Promise.promisifyAll(require("mongodb"));
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

MongoClient
.connect('the_URL_of_my_database')
.then( (database) => {
  var db = database;
  var myCollection = database.collection('my_collection');

  myCollection
  .find('my_awesome_selector')
  .forEach( (document) => {
    
    var selector = {hashkey: document.hashkey};
    var update = {$set: {data: 'my_new_data'}};
    
    myCollection
    .updateOne(selector, update)
    .then( (response) => {
      // do something if needed
    })
    .catch( (err) => {/*update error handling*/});
    
  })
  .then( (/*do we get some kind of input here ?*/) => {
    // do something once EVERY document has been updated
  })
  .catch( (err) => {/*forEach error handling*/});

})
.catch( (err) => {/*connection error handling*/});
```

My questions are :

1. What does the promisified .forEach() return ? Is it a promise that will be resolved once ALL documents have been updated ?
2. If my code doesn't work, any idea on how to implement it correctly ?

[Optional questions that would help me greatly :]

1. I have noticed the .each() method in the MongoDB driver. It is marked as "deprecated", but is there any use for it, or should I stick to .forEach() ?
2. Does the entire snippet make sense to you, or are there any rookie mistakes/improvements I should be aware of ?

Thanks a lot for any answer or advice !

[EDIT : I precised the update. I feel like I'm in callback hell all over again]

Comment: If you use `promisifyAll`, then `.forEach` is not altered at all. It would be `.forEachAsync` that returned a promise. However, a collection's `forEach` callback is not a nodeback but an iterator, so you cannot promisify it at all.

Comment: @Bergi : I understand my mistake. But then, how can I achieve the sequence : (1) select a set of documents in a collection, with or without a cursor; (2) perform an operation for each selected document ; (3) do something else once all previous operations are resolved ?

Comment: IIRC, `.toArrayAsync` works and then lets you use the promise-aware iteration methods from Bluebird

Comment: How do I use `promisifyAll`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need bluebird for any of this. The mongo driver has built in promises. Since `forEach` doesn't return anything, you can use `map()` to process each document update into a promise, use `toArray()` to reduce them into an array of promises, and then `Promise.all()` to resolve each promise within that array:

```
var mongodb = require("mongodb");
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

MongoClient
  .connect('the_URL_of_my_database')
  .then((db) => {

    var myCollection = db.collection('my_collection');

    myCollection.find({})
      .map((document) => {

        var selector = { _id: document._id };
        var update = { $set: { data: 'my_new_data' } };
        return myCollection
          .updateOne(selector, update)
          .then((response) => {
            // this is each resolved updateOne. You don't need
            // this `.then` unless you want to post-process
            // each individual resolved updateOne result
            console.log(response.result);
            // return each value to accumulate it in Promise.all.then()
            return response.result;
          });
      })
      .toArray() // accumulate the .map returned promises
      .then((promises) => Promise.all(promises)) // iterate through and resolve each updateOne promise
      .then((resolvedPromises) => {
        // an array of all the results returned from each updateOne
        console.log(resolvedPromises);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // error handle the entire chain.
      });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // error handle the connection
  });
```

> I have noticed the .each() method in the MongoDB driver. It is marked as "deprecated", but is there any use for it, or should I stick to .forEach() ?

I assume `.each()` was deprecated in favor of `.forEach()` for consistency with the `Array` prototype.

Comment: Yup, as I spent time in mongodb driver I became aware that promises are now built in ! Thanks a lot for those explanations. I get the idea, now I guess I'll have to spend some time digesting it all ;-)

Comment: This method also requires you load all data into memory. Need a way to use promises with cursors.

Comment: @chovy if you're worried about memory, you're better off using streams than promises.

Comment: It only pulls however much you can handle. If you want to ask a question or link to one you've asked, I can answer it there.